# Apache mod_proxy - AJAX and www prefix

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm currently facing interesting problem which I cannot resolve. I have an Apache2 as a proxy to Tomcat. The proxy configuration looks like:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests       Off
ProxyPreserveHost   On
ProxyPass           /myApp       http://localhost:8080/myApp
ProxyPassReverse    /myApp       http://localhost:8080/myApp
```

Everything works fine, the problem come with AJAX within my application. When I go to myApp url: http://myurl.com/myApp I can access ajax only using the same url. When I use www url prefix (http://www.myurl.com/myApp) for AJAX the ajax content is not loaded (apache logs HTTP 302). This also doesn't work vice versa. I'm pretty sure that I can correct it in Apache, but I don't know how. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks for any help,

Mateo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one host name to be canonical and redirect to it from the other.

e.g. (If I'm remembering my Apache syntax right)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively (or additionally). Use root relative URIs (i.e. those which start with `/foo` instead of `http://example.com/foo`) so that requests stay on the same host.

Comment: The "alternatively" suggestion helped. I didn't know that it will work like that. Thanks for your help!:-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some .htaccess  for redirection ?